# DAX - Retrieve a value from another unrelated table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables: 'Events' and 'Occurrences'.
In Events, I have the name of the event, start date and end date.
In 'Occurrences' I have a date from occurrence, ID occurrence and description of occurrence.

**Events Table**

| Event | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Event 1 | 01/01/2022 | 02/14/2022 |
| Event 2 | 02/15/2022 | 03/10/2022 |
| Event 3 | 02/11/2022 | 03/30/2022 |

**Occurrence Table**

| ID Ocurrence | Occurrence Create Date | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/10/2022 | Foo 1 |
| 2 | 02/11/2022 | Foo 2 |
| 3 | 02/20/2022 | Foo 3 |
| 4 | 03/20/2022 | Foo 4 |
| 5 | 03/30/2022 | Foo 5 |

My Question is: How can I retrieve which event is each occurrence?
In this example, the expected result is:

| ID Ocurrence | Occurrence Create Date | Description | Event Related |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/10/2022 | Foo 1 | **Event 1** |
| 2 | 02/11/2022 | Foo 2 | **Event 1** |
| 3 | 02/20/2022 | Foo 3 | **Event 2** |
| 4 | 03/20/2022 | Foo 4 | **Event 3** |
| 5 | 03/30/2022 | Foo 5 | **Event 3** |

Comment: Can it be 2 related events? And what do you expect calc column or visual?

Comment: Not. There are no two events simultaneously. Thus, each occurrence will be only one event. And, I need a column in an Occurrence table.

Comment: It will be a problem with the 30th of Feb )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this measure to your table...

```
Event Related =
VAR _occ =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table (2)'[Occurrence Create Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        FIRSTNONBLANK ( 'Table'[Event], 1 ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Table' ),
            'Table'[Start Date] <= _occ
                && 'Table'[End Date] >= _occ
        )
    )
```

[image: add measure as a column]

[image: sample]

or if you want to add only as a column to the table, not the visual, you can use this calculated column (more or less the same)

```
Event Related 2 = 
var _occ = 'Table (2)'[Occurrence Create Date] 
  return
    
    CALCULATE (
        FIRSTNONBLANK ( 'Table'[Event], 1 ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Table' ),
            'Table'[Start Date] <= _occ
                && 'Table'[End Date] >= _occ
        )
    )
```

Comment: Hi Umut, OP wants a column.

Comment: Hi @Mik , OP can add this measure to the table as a column, simple... see my pic 